# procedure with month calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table named `Data`

coloumns are `Id,Name,Supply,Demand,Date,Value`

Create a procedure where

Column `q1` will contain the Supply Index of Quarter-1 (JAN-MAR, sum of supply/sum of demand),

`q2` will contain the Supply Index of Quarter-2 (APR-JUN, sum of supply/sum of demand),

`q3` will contain the Supply Index of Quarter-3 (JUL-SEP, sum of supply/sum of demand),

`Q4` will contain the Supply Index of q4 (OCT-DEC, sum of supply/sum of demand), `YR` will contain the Supply Index of given year (JAN-DEC, sum of supply/sum of demand), and it is separated by value

sample input:

```
ID      Name     Suppply    Demand     date          value
1        A         10        5         01 04 2001    20
2        B          4        1         01 04 2001    20
3        A          4        2         02 01 2005    10
4        A          4        2         02 02 2005    10
5        B          4        1         01 07 2001    20
```

expected output

```
Name   value    q1    q2     q3    q4
A         10    4     0      0     0
A         20    0     2      0     0
B         20    0     4      4     0
```

Comment: Your expected output doesn't match your description of the expected output. Looking at the expected output, I have no idea what Strength is, or how A has 4 in Q1. Given this, it's a bit difficult to give an answer.

Comment: From our faq: *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.* We're not here to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want something like this :

```
CREATE TABLE #test 
  ( 
     id     INT, 
     name   CHAR(1), 
     supply INT, 
     demand INT, 
     dates  DATE, 
     value  INT 
  ) 

INSERT INTO #test 
VALUES     (1, 
            'A', 
            10, 
            5, 
            '20010401', 
            20) 

INSERT INTO #test 
VALUES     (2, 
            'B', 
            4, 
            1, 
            '20010401', 
            20) 

INSERT INTO #test 
VALUES     (3, 
            'A', 
            4, 
            2, 
            '20050102', 
            10) 

INSERT INTO #test 
VALUES     (4, 
           'A', 
            4, 
            2, 
           '20050202', 
            10) 

INSERT INTO #test 
VALUES     (5, 
            'B', 
            4, 
            1, 
            '20010107', 
            20) 

SELECT name, 
       value, 
       Isnull([q1], 0), 
       Isnull([q2], 0), 
       Isnull([q3], 0), 
       Isnull([q4], 0) 
FROM   (SELECT 'q' + Rtrim(Datepart(q, dates)) AS quarters, 
               name, 
               Sum(supply) / Sum(demand)       AS val, 
               value 
        FROM   #test 
        GROUP  BY Datepart(q, dates), 
                  name, 
                  value) p 
       PIVOT ( Sum(val) 
             FOR quarters IN ([Q1], 
                              [Q2], 
                              [Q3], 
                              [Q4])) AS pivottable; 

drop table #test
```

Next time please try to organize more your text :)

Comment: can u tell me Rtrim(Datepart(q, dates)) what does it mean?

Comment: oh it's an error i do often, i do an rtrim because rtrim make a cast as varchar and it's shorter to write.